# Is there a way to end all sessions for a subject ID?

Tags: identityserver4

What I'd like to do is end **all** sessions for a user when a user changes/resets their password (using ASP.NET Core Identity). I'm using the oidc-client-js library inside of a SPA. I've figured out how to end the current session for a user and cause any tabs that're in that same session (say, other tabs in the same browser windows) to recognize the session is over via the check session iFrame, but any other sessions (say in an incognito window) still seem to have the session functioning, even if their refresh tokens/all persisted grants for that subject ID have been revoked.

Is there some way to make that iFrame return to the client that the session is over for all sessions, like maybe have the iFrame page be checking the persisted grants for that session or something? I'm okay if a currently issued access_token continues working (they're short-lived), but just want the refresh tokens to be invalidated and the session to end.

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1

There is an OpenID Connect Session draft specification which would do what you want - it allows front end clients to check the current session state via an iframe. This is a draft and may not be implemented by ASP.NET Core Identity though.

https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html

### Option 2

An alternative mechanism for resolving your problem programatically is by putting a check in your token exchange code. Your access tokens will presumably be relatively short lived, and so the front end has to regularly acquire new access tokens (either via refresh token, or by id token on the implicit flow for instance.

In your token exchange you could check for timestamp when the password was last updated.

If it is more recent than the timestamp when the token was issued, then instead of issuing the fresh access token you could return a 401 and manage a redirect to your authentication endpoint by a mechanism of your choice.

This doesn't instantly log the user out of alternative browser windows, because it depends upon the expiry window of your access tokens. If does have the advantage of working cross browser though, because it doesn't depend upon browser specific session information. It can also check for customers who are blacklisted, or who have changed their email address and other checks which might be relevant to a desire to force re-authentication.

For belt and braces you can use both these techniques.